# 1991 lexus ls400 v8 AC condenser removal

Tags: ac, lexus

I recently crashed my Lexus ls400 and damaged the ac condenser, I don't really want to waste cash on it what can I do to cancel AC system?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the A/C, just leave everything where it's at. You may want to fix it in the future, so if everything is there, all you have to do is fix what's wrong and there you are. The pulley will spin freely, so no big deal there. If the refrigerant is all out of the system, it won't attempt to turn on. It's just a little bit of unused weight in the vehicle.

Comment: so my car wont run?

Comment: Car will run with everything in place. It won't have any effect on how it runs. If there is damage which you haven't explained, obviously *that* will have to get fixed in order for it to run, but you don't have to do a thing to the AC parts. Beyond that, maybe I'm not understanding what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

A few things in addition to Paulster's answer

If you want to completely remove the A/C compressor, go to a shop first and have them drain the refrigerant.  Do not let it vent into the atmosphere.  Even if the system is not working, there is likely a little bit left.  You do not need to remove the compressor, leaving it will not hurt anything.

Depending on the belt configuration, you may be able to either run without the A/C belt, or get a shorter belt that does not wrap around the A/C pulley.